# problem with react prop where my function works in one context but not another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, prop

These two functions look the same to me. But only the first one generates the images from `this.state.images` I would love any help with this probably simple mistake.

This works

```
   {this.state.images.map((image, i) => (
     <Image src={image.img}  />
   ))}
```

This does not work

```
generateImage() {
 this.state.images.map((image) => {
  return image.img;
 });
}

<Image src={this.generateImage()}  />
```

Edit:

It is now displaying correctly. I am now trying to have it only display a single image, one whose state of `beenCalled` is `false`. The problem is is that it is going to render all of the images whose state of `beenCalled` is `false`. Not sure how to make the if statement stop once it has been fulfilled once.

```
generateImage() {
 return this.state.images.map((image, i) => {
   if(image.beenCalled === false) {
    return  <Image src={image.img} index={i} />
   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your array:

```js
generateImage() {
 return this.state.images.map((image) => {
  return image.img;
 });
}
```

Also if you have multiple images, you normally need to create one `<Image src={...} />` for each image.

Comment: totally works! so strange to have to return two things?

Comment: Well you have 2 functions here :) Each one needs to return a value.

Comment: ahh makes sense. gotcha

Comment: no problem :) don't forget to accept the answer! I want my rep! ^^